# R - openXL not working in openxlxs package

Tags: r, openxlsx

the openXL function is not working in the openxlsx package.
I've uninstalled then reinstalled but no luck.
Oddly enough it works for the reprex below but not in any of my other scripts.
Any ideas why this is? Thank you.

```
library(openxlsx)
setwd(getwd())
wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "test")
somedata <- "data"
writeData(wb, 1, somedata)

saveWorkbook(wb, "temp.xlsx", TRUE)
openXL(wb)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? If you get error messages you should include them in your question.

Comment: Hi @Marius Nothing happens, no message at all... It just doesn't open the Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, this may work:

```
shell(shQuote(string = wb$saveWorkbook()), wait = TRUE)
```

It is the same command called by openXL, except for the argument wait, that is set to TRUE.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo Hiramoto - where do I paste this into?

Comment: Just replace the openXL(wb) row with it.